# Python 3 Input(prompt) function

Tags: python

I know this might be a simple question but I can't seem to figure how to put a string after the for loop variable

```
stud_num = int(input("How many students do you have? "))
test_num = int(input("How many test for your module? "))
score = 0
for i in range(stud_num):
    print("******** Student #", i+1, "********")
    for s in range(test_num):
        print("Test number ", end="")
        score1 = float(input(s+1))
        score += score1
```

My sample output for asking the question would be

Test number 1 :

but now my current output from

```
print("Test number ", end="")
```

`score1 = float(input(s+1))` is
Test number 1

I can't figure out how to put the `": "` into the input because it gives me an error saying that it expects an `int` but gets a `str`

Comment: try `input(str(s+1))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it still doesn't work, it still gives me the same error, expected type int but got str

Comment: we didn't see `stud_num` and `test_num` but I suppose you forgot to convert to int after input (this isn't a [mcve])

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I did convert to int after input

Comment: then show a [mcve], else it's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just edited my question, sorry

Comment: don't sum up tracebacks, just paste the error & traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't split your prompt between a `print` and the `input`. Just use a format string in the `input` prompt:

```
score1 = float(input("Test number %d: " % (s+1)))
```

Or using `str.format`:

```
score1 = float(input("Test number {}: ".format(s+1)))
```

Comment: @JHBonarius I was trying to but it said I couldn't accept an answer so fast? It's telling me I can accept in 2 mins

Comment: @JHBonarius Haha yea!

Answer (score 0):

OR the new f-strings, only allowed after python 3.6:

```
score1 = float(input(f"Test number {s+1}: "))
```